# 404 error from binding a background url even with ng-cloak

Tags: angularjs

I am binding the background url css property in this way:

```
<div class="ng-cloak" style="background-image: url({{image.url}})"></div>
```

all the images are loaded correctly but in the console I have:

```
GET http://localhost:8100/%7B%7Bimage.url%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)
```

even if I use the class `ng-cloak`.
Does someone know how to avoid this error and this bad request?

Comment: Have you tried [ngStyle](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle)?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use ng-style instead because angular will not check none ng-*
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle